# Working with byobu splits

Tags: byobu, split

Is there a way to start automatically a window with multiple splits running their own application using byobu? am using tmux as the backend.
 Also, how do i select the content of a split for pasting later?  When i tried this with the mouse.it also included the content of the adjacent split.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed start byobu or tmux with multiple windows or splits, either running the default shell or any program you want. See the [tmux man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tmux.1.html) for a full list and descriptions of all commands accepted by tmux.

In general, any tmux command can be passed as arguments to byobu. Multiple commands can be chained together using `\;`. Here are some example usages that may help you do what you want.

#### Start byobu with 3 shell windows

```
byobu new-session \; new-window -d \; new-window -d
```

#### Start byobu with a shell and vim in a side-by-side split

```
byobu new-session \; split-window -d -h vim
```

#### Start byobu with 2 vims in stacked split and a second window

```
byobu new-session vim \; split-window -d vim \; new-window -d
```

---

As to your question about copying text from a split (I assume you mean a side-by-side split), the best option is probably to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to temporarily zoom the split to take up the whole window. After copying the text, the split can be restored with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> again.

Comment: I can't use Shift+F11 in OS X? Is there different shortcut?